# Laravel multipule relationships count

Tags: php, laravel

I have these models:
ForumCategory
Forum
Topic
Reply

In the main forum page, I want to count and display the number of replies that associated to this forum.
All the models have relationships.

This is the view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default striped">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-11"><a href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 text-right"><a><span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @foreach ($category->forums as $forum)
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 text-right"><span class="fa fa-envelope fa-4x"></span></div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <h4>
                                <a href="forum/{{ $forum->id }}/{{ urlencode($forum->name) }}">{{ $forum->name }} </a>
                                <br>
                                <small>{{ $forum->description }}</small>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 post-num">
                            <h5>{{ $forum->topics->count() }}<br>
                            <small>Topics</small></h5>
                            <h5>{{ $forum->topics->replies->count() }}<br>
                            <small>Replies</small></h5>                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="" class="img-circle last-comnt-img">
                            <a href="#">Last comment</a><br>
                            By <a href="#">Username</a><br>
                            <span class="text-muted">12:31</span>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

This line won't work:

```
$forum->topics->replies->count()
```

Comment: You can set the `->hasManyThrough()` relationship in your Forum model.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!